# Modify the token returned by Struts2 s:token tag

Tags: struts2, jsp-tags

In a Struts 2 webapp (which also uses Spring), 
I want to modify the `"output"` of the [`<s:token>`](https://struts.apache.org/docs/token.html) tag to use my own token-generation algorithm.

It appears the `<s:token>` tag is handled by a class called [`org.apache.struts2.components.Token`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.3.12/org/apache/struts2/components/Token.java), which is a [`UIBean`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.3.12/org/apache/struts2/components/UIBean.java#UIBean). Is there a standard way using either Struts or Spring by which I can "extend" or "modify" or replace the `Token` class, or the methods it uses to generate tokens?

Alternatively, can I make up my own `<mytoken>` tag that works in Struts 2?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @Aleksandr M, I have a stateless server requirement. I need to be able to generate a token that can be re-computed by the server. As only token-generation and validation needs to be replaced, I would like to drop in my components to work within existing Struts 2 framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment in the latest S2 version `2.3.20` there is no simple way of doing that. The [`TokenHelper`](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/STRUTS_2_3_20/core/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/util/TokenHelper.java) class which is responsible for generating tokens is a simple utility class with static methods.

You are better off using your own custom token solution. You need an interceptor which will handle tokens and something that will put token into JSP. For that you can create custom tag or just use a hidden input which calls some method in your base action.

Note: The [`execAndWait`](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/STRUTS_2_3_20/core/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/ExecuteAndWaitInterceptor.java#L260) interceptor uses `TokenHelper` too, so if you are using `execAndWait` you need to change it as well.

Comment: :'( Thx! Are you able to quickly describe or link to a minimal way to make custom tokens? If so I will mark as answered.

Comment: @0xbe5077ed: What do you mean? Have you seen a `TokenHelper` class?

Comment: I meant custom *tag*, not token&mdash;got the token part covered :). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @0xbe5077ed: As I've mentioned you can just use hidden field with value populated from some base action. Explaining how to create a custom tag is OT on this question. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/taglib/quickstart.html.